# Robot framework: Get multiple files from remote location to target directory

Tags: automation, robotframework

With Robot Framework, Is there a way to copy multiple files from a dir to local directory?

I see `Get File` keyword in SSHLibrary.
It supports copying multiple files but doesn't work when target directory is specified.

If we specify only one file to be copied, the target directory argument works.
If multiple files are specified in source (e.g. /path/*.ext) and target directory is speciifed, then I get this error:

```
Cannot copy multiple source files to one destination file
```

If I remove target directory as argument then all files get copied to execution directory, which I want to avoid.

Here is a stub:

```
Get Remote files 
     [Arguments]    ${HOST} ${ROOT_PASS}    ${TARGET_DIR}
     Open Connection  ${HOST}
     Login  ${ROOT_USER}    ${ROOT_PASS}
     Log To Console     Logged in to server
     SSHLibrary.Get File    //*.ext ${TARGET_DIR}
     Log To Console     Files copied to ${TARGET_DIR}
```

Comment: when you specify the directory, how do you do it? Does the directory end with "/" (or "\" on windows)? Does the target directory exist?

Comment: I'm working on windows.
Target directory is specified as absolute path (not ending with /) and it already exists.

Comment: Can you show the exact way you are calling the keyword?

Comment: I'm using SSHLibrary to get files from remote server.
see http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/latest/SSHLibrary.html#Get%20File

Comment: I understand that. It would help to see how you're calling the keyword. It's hard to find bugs in code without seeing the actual code.

Comment: Here is a stub:

`Get Remote files` 
`[Arguments] ${HOST} ${ROOT_PASS} ${TARGET_DIR}`
`Open Connection  ${HOST}`
`Login  ${ROOT_USER} ${ROOT_PASS}`
`Log To Console  Logged in to server`
`SSHLibrary.Get File //*.ext ${TARGET_DIR}`
`Log To Console  Files copied to ${TARGET_DIR}`

Comment: Please put that code in your question. It's impossible to read in the comments.

Comment: There is only a single space between `//*.ext` and  `${TARGET_DIR}`. Is that intentional, or a typographical error? Also, why two forward slashes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90027/discussion-between-arpit-jain-and-bryan-oakley).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download multiple files from folder present inside some other folder, then you can use `**Get Directory**` and `**List Directories In Directory**` methods of SSH library.

1. Create a keyword 'Get Folder from remote server and copy it' that takes two arguments : Source folder path and destination folder path.

   ```
   ***Keywords***
   Get Folder from remote server and copy it
       [Documentation]    Used to copy Folder within Folder from some source location(can be from local or remote machine) to destination location(can be into local or remote machine)
       [Arguments]    ${source}    ${destination}
       Log To Console    \n--------------------------------Copying Result folder from remote machine to local machine      
       Get Directory    ${source}    ${destination}
       @{directories}    List Directories In Directory    ${source}
       : FOR    ${dir}    IN    @{directories}
       \    ${currentSrc}    Catenate    SEPARATOR=     ${source}    ${dir}           
       \    ${currentDestination}    Catenate    SEPARATOR=     ${destination}    ${dir}
       \    Get Directory    ${currentSrc}    ${currentDestination}
   ```
2. Call this keyword inside your testcases.

   ```
   *** Test Cases ***
   Copy multiple files    
       Get Folder from remote server and copy it locally    ${Resultsource}  ${Resultdestination}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the test robot script which got all the files successfully to the targeted directory in the local machine from remote machine.

Trick is to end the targeted directory with / (use ${/} for platform indepenent, say C:${/}temp${/} to tell C:/temp/ on windows, anyway linux example given below)

```
*** Settings ***

Library                SSHLibrary

*** Variables ***
${SERVER}                   192.168.0.1
${SYSTEM_USER}                  app1
${SYSTEM_PASSWORD}              app1xxx
${QUERY}                        /home/app1/test/configuration/*.props
${TARGET_DIR}                   /tmp/test/
*** Test Cases ***


Get Multiple Files To A Directory
    [tags]              multi-files
    Get Remote files  ${SERVER}     ${SYSTEM_USER}  ${SYSTEM_PASSWORD}  ${QUERY}    ${TARGET_DIR}

*** Keywords ***
Get Remote files
     [Arguments]    ${host}     ${user}     ${pwd}    ${query}     ${dir}
     Open Connection  ${host}
     Login  ${user}    ${pwd}
     Log To Console     Logged in to server
     SSHLibrary.Get File    ${query}    ${dir}
     Log To Console     Files copied to ${TARGET_DIR}
     close all connections
```

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming a bug in the SSHLibrary documentation.

From the documentation for get file:

```
1. If the destination is an existing file, the source file is downloaded over it.
2. If the destination is an existing directory, the source file is downloaded into it. Possible file with the same name is overwritten.
3. If the destination does not exist and it ends with the path separator of the local operating system, it is considered a directory. The directory is then created and the source file is downloaded into it. Possible missing intermediate directories are also created.
4. If the destination does not exist and does not end with the local path separator, it is considered a file. The source file is downloaded and saved using that file name, and possible missing intermediate directories are also created.
```

I am assuming that for (2) just like for (3), you need a trailing / on the target folder.

You can also try pointing to a non existing folder (that will be created on the spot) - again with a trailing /

Comment: Yes, I am using SSHLibrary.
I've posted this question after trying all these combinations None of these work..
For now i firstly copy required files to local working dir of ROBOT and then move them to my dest dir with 'Move Files' keyword from OperatingSystem library. 
robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/